# Deno DB connection hangs after close

Tags: database, typescript, deno

So I've got the below setup for simple testing purposes.

```
import { MySQLConnector, Database } from 'https://deno.land/x/denodb@v1.0.39/mod.ts';

console.log('I LOGGED 1');

const connection = new MySQLConnector({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'db_name',
    username: 'db_user',
    password: 'db_pass'
});

console.log('I LOGGED 2');

const db = new Database(connection);

console.log('I LOGGED 3');

await db.close();
await connection.close();

console.log('I LOGGED 4');
```

However when the script is run with `deno run ./test.ts` the CLI hangs and has to be manually closed with `CTRL + C`. Not sure at all why this is happening. Additionally it still occurs even if I change the above to the below

```
import { MySQLConnector, Database } from 'https://deno.land/x/denodb@v1.0.39/mod.ts';

const connection = new MySQLConnector({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'db_name',
    username: 'db_user',
    password: 'db_pass'
});
```

The CLI just hangs...

Comment: Which line does it hang on? (You could use a debugger or add `console.log` statements to determine such.) I've not used `denodb` before but from the docs I'm thinking you might not need to explicitly close the `connection` but I'm not sure.

Comment: @mfulton26 have edited my question to provide logs. They all output, deno just hangs at the end of the script for some reason unless `Deno.exit()` is called. It's not a massive issue but it is a concern that *something* is causing deno to not fully execute the script.

Comment: it looks like `denodb` (third party library) depends on https://deno.land/x/mysql (also a third party library) so the issue might in that project